# Jenkinsfile pipeline, return warning but do not fail

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to not fail with a declarative pipeline step but display a warning instead? At the moment I am circumventing it by adding `|| exit 0` to the end of the sh command lines so it always exits ok.

Example currently:

`sh 'vendor/bin/phpcs --report=checkstyle --report-file=build/checkstyle.xml --standard=phpcs.xml . || exit 0'`

I feel there should be a better way of doing this? How can you control the result returned so the user knows with out digging through result logs but with out blocking/failing too?

Thank you

Edit:

So I have got this far to be able to mark it as unstable. In Blue Ocean it just marks every stage as unstable though and you have to go digging through to find it. Am I trying to do the impossible (but feels like I should be able to do it)?

Also it just displays it as 'Shell script' in the heading on Blue Sky now instead of showing the command being run so you don't even know what it's doing with out expanding each of them.

```
script {
  def RESULT = sh returnStatus: true, script: 'vendor/bin/phpcs --report=checkstyle --report-file=build/checkstyle.xml --standard=phpcs.xml .'
  if ( RESULT != 0 ) {
    currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
  }
}
```

Re marking it all yellow/unstable: Just found this which explains that I am not going mad. Several years of discussion and no progress :( https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39203

Re it just showing 'Shell script' now on Blue Ocean view: I'll go and play some more and see if I'm better with `|| exit 0` or a script block and using echo to display some useful info.

Answer (score 9):

FYI: [JENKINS-39203](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39203) has been resolved in the meantime.

Instead of setting `currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'` we use the corresponding basic pipeline step [`unstable`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#unstable-set-stage-result-to-unstable), which also takes a message:

```
unstable("There are Checkstyle issues")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find options for any steps in your jenkins itself under `http://jenkins-url/pipeline-syntax/`. sh with returnStatus: true can be used to achieve your goal.

```
sh returnStatus: true, script: 'ls -2' # returnStatus: true, just set $? but not fail the execution
```

*Below pasted the screenshot from pipeline-syntax page:*
[image: Screenshot from pipeline-syntax page]